# "ruby-2.0.0-p0 is not installed" after trying to install with RVM

Tags: rvm, ruby-2.0

If I run `rvm install 2.0.0`, it goes through the normal steps (downloading, extracting, configuring, compiling, installing), but ends by simply saying:

```
ruby-2.0.0-p0 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0'
```

I've tried the following:

- `rvm remove 2.0.0`
- `rvm get head`
- `rvm requirements`
- `rvm install ruby-2.0.0`

I keep getting the same result: no error, it just "is not installed." Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: I've got the same issue

Comment: any progress yet? i got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to work it out.

When I did an `echo $CC` it came up with `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`. So I did an `export CC=clang`, then `rvm reinstall 2.0.0` and it worked.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

rvm get ruby here => http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/

Maybe you should get the right ruby version to install. Something like ruby-2.0.0-rc1 or ruby-2.0.0-rc2 is the latest ruby version.

Comment: The 'rc' versions are release candidates, meaning 1) they come before the full, `p0` (patch level 0) release and 2) they're more likely to be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this message **when you open a Rails folder**, then you need to remove the .ruby-version file which is inside the folder and re-run a `bundle install`:

```
rm .ruby-version
bundle install
```